# Traefik IngressRouteTCP can't handle HTTP2

Tags: azure-aks, cloudflare, traefik, http2, sni

I have an `IngressRouteTCP` configured for Traefik running in an AKS cluster (behind an Azure load balancer). I'm trying to do routing based on SNI, rather than on the hostname header. The certificate is generated by Cloudflare for `test.example.com`.

As you can see below, it doesn't work. What does work, is setting a `TLSOption` with `alpnProtocols` to `http/1.1`. But that would default to http/1 as I understand it. My application supports http2, so I'd prefer to use that.

I'm not sure why it fails? Is it Traefik, curl or the application?

Testing it with `curl -svk --connect-to test.example.com:443:my-azure-load-balancer.cloudapp.azure.com:443 https://test.example.com` gives this:

```
* Connecting to hostname: my-azure-load-balancer.cloudapp.azure.com
* Connecting to port: 443
*   Trying x.x.x.x:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my-azure-load-balancer.cloudapp.azure.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=CloudFlare, Inc.; OU=CloudFlare Origin CA; CN=CloudFlare Origin Certificate
*  start date: Sep 20 12:40:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 16 12:40:00 2037 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=CloudFlare, Inc.; OU=CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority; L=San Francisco; ST=California
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x558d30129860)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: test.example.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* http2 error: Remote peer returned unexpected data while we expected SETTINGS frame.  Perhaps, peer does not support HTTP/2 properly.
* Connection #0 to host my-azure-load-balancer.cloudapp.azure.com left intact
```

I'm using Traefik version `2.9.1`

This is my Kubernetes configuration

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami:v1.6.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      name: whoami
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`test.example.com`)
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
  tls:
    secretName: cloudflare-cert
```

These are the only logs related to this that I can find in the logs (the second log line doesn't always come though):

```
traefik-c757597b9-2xv65 time="2022-10-31T08:52:59Z" level=debug msg="Handling connection from 10.9.3.227:61988 to 10.9.3.73:80"
traefik-c757597b9-2xv65 time="2022-10-31T08:52:59Z" level=debug msg="Error during connection: read tcp 10.9.3.58:34400->10.9.3.73:80: read: connection reset by peer"
```

Those IPs are:

- `10.9.3.227` - The Kubernetes node
- `10.9.3.58` - Traefik
- `10.9.3.73` - The service for the whoami pod

I initially tested this behind Cloudflare, and received this:
[image]